# Plotting 3D data as an image in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have data in 3 dimensions. I would like to plot the first two dimensions and colorize by the third. I want it show up as an image like hist2d would do, except instead of being colorized by the occupation of the first two dimensions, I want it to be colorized by the third dimension. I think this will require binning everything. How can this be achieved?

Example data:

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=2, size=100)
y = np.random.normal(loc=25, scale=5, size=100)
z = np.cos(x)+np.sin(y)
```

I want to plot x vs y and colorize by the intensity z. But, not just a scatterplot, I want it to come out as an image like [this](https://matplotlib.org/_images/pcolor_demo.png).

Comment: What do you mean colorize by third ?

Comment: Could you provide a small example of your data? so we can understand what you are looking for. [`pcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html`) maybe is useful?

Comment: @xdze2 I have clarified in the edit

Comment: Try to use one of the functions listed in the image you show and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist tried them, didn't work, hence my question

Comment: @MadPhysicist more specifically, `pcolor(x, y, z)` gives `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution, since the data is not structured on a grid is to use [`tripcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=tripcolor#matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor) from `matplotlib` (there is also [`tricontourf`](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=tricontourf#matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=2, size=100)
y = np.random.normal(loc=25, scale=5, size=100)
z = np.cos(x)+np.sin(y)

plt.tripcolor(x, y, z);
plt.plot(x, y, '.k');
```

[image: example using tricolor]

The other solution is, prior to the visualization, to interpolated the data on a regular grid using, for instance, `griddata` from Scipy:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# define the grid
x_fine = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 200)
y_fine = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 200)

x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_fine, y_fine)

# interpolate the data:
z_grid = griddata((x, y), z, (x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()), method='cubic').reshape(x_grid.shape)

plt.pcolor(x_fine, y_fine, z_grid);
plt.plot(x, y, '.k');
```

[image: using griddata first]

Comment: Thanks, I think this is on the right track. However when I run this, it just comes out as a solid color with also a warning `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  cbook._putmask(xa, xa < 0.0, -1)`. Any idea?

Comment: the code is working on my pc, I am trying to upload the graphs. Is it when you try with your real data?

Answer (score 0):

I use [ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot.html) for R, not so much for python, but, here's a sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# is this the best implementation of ggplot?
from plotnine import *

x = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=2, size=100)
y = np.random.normal(loc=25, scale=5, size=100)
z = np.cos(x)+np.sin(y)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z})

p = ggplot(df, aes(x='x', y='y', colour='z')) + geom_point()
p = p + scale_color_distiller(type='div', palette='RdYlBu')
p
```